# How to achieve realtime usb storage detection with Ruby on Linux?

Tags: ruby, linux, dbus, libusb

I am thinking ruby-dbus could be the right solution, but I cannot seem to find any examples of how to detect in realtime, whenever a storage device is connected to the Linux machine. Anyone have such an example?

Comment: Please read "[ask]". You're asking us to recommend off-site resources, which is off-topic.

Comment: I'm not, I'm asking how to achieve realtime usb storage detection with Ruby on Linux. A bit of sample code would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be numerous different approaches you could take.
[Here's a Ruby implementation I found](https://github.com/larskanis/libusb) that links into `libusb` with Ruby FFI.

What's good about this is that libusb supports hotplug notifications, so this could be something that does what you need:
http://libusb.sourceforge.net/api-1.0/hotplug.html

From the [libusb Ruby docs](https://github.com/larskanis/libusb#device-hotplug-support):

> **Device hotplug support**
>
> Support for device hotplugging can be used, if `LIBUSB.has_capability?(:CAP_HAS_HOTPLUG)` returns true. This requires libusb-1.0.16 or newer on Linux or MacOS. Windows support is still on the way.
>
> A hotplug event handler can be registered with {`LIBUSB::Context#on_hotplug_event`}. You then need to call {`LIBUSB::Context#handle_events`} in order to receive any events. This can be done as blocking calls (possibly in it's own thread) or by using {`LIBUSB::Context#pollfds`} to detect any events to handle.

Comment: Thank you for that, I didn't realise libusb has hotplug support, that's perfect!